# Comparing 2D data sets using python

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Thanks in advance for everyone reading this question.

I have to write a program that takes a 2D data set (Force[y axis] versus displacement[x axis] data, if it matters), compare it with around 600 2D data sets and find the closest data set to the input data.

The 2D data sets are non-parametric and independent, i.e have no kind of distribution nor share same values/interval $\Delta x$ for X-coordinates within a data set or between two data sets. All the data sets (including input data set) either have positive or negative slope.

I plotted 3 of 600 data sets just for reference.

[image]

What statistical parameters should be compared ? What statistical tests should I use ?

Clarification on problem :  I have a library of force versus displacement graphs for different materials.  Usually, a customer/user gives me a force vs disp graph for their part behaviour.  I would search my library and tell them which material force vs disp graph is closer and hence it is better to use that material for the part.

What do I mean by "close" ?

1) Two graphs should always have an overlapping displacement domain (at least tiny bit). If there is no overlap there is no point in comparison.

Physical explanation : If the customer part has a displacement range of 0 to 10 mm.  There is no point in looking at materials that have displacement range  11 to 50 mm.

2) It is preferred to have a force greater than or equal to the input force for a displacement, as designing the part with a material that can withstand a smaller force will definitely break it.

P.S:- I feel I did not include some information to understand the problem better.  The state of my knowledge now is such that I don't know what more relevant information should I include.  Please specify further information you need, so that I can include it as promptly as I can.

Comment: 1) How exactly is "closest" defined? 2) You mentioned that the goal is to find the closest dataset in the collection. Based on the information given, I'm not sure I see why any kind of statistical test would be necessary. Perhaps you could elaborate on this--what would you be testing and why?

Comment: I have added the necessary details in the question @user20160

Answer (score 0):

Since we can assume that displacement is a continuous, at least locally differentiable function of force, proving overlap of the two lines requires that:

$$
min(ref) \le min(opt) < max(ref) \\
\&\&\\
min(ref) < max(opt) \le max(ref) 
$$

Where $opt$ is (one of) your material's and $ref$ is the client's reference material's displacement domains, which is a fairly straightforward check. Note that you don't even need to have the coordinates match up on both domains, you just need the endpoints!

---

For the similarity, first off, since you favor stronger materials, we'll need an asymmetric loss to reflect that.

Second off, the relevant bit is how the material responds to force, and whether it can perform well enough for the client's spec.

So, the 'natural' slopes to calculate are actually the ones given by $\frac{X_N-X_{N-1}}{Y_N-Y_{N-1}}$ instead of the other way round, which is how you would usually function graphs.

To deal with the potential coordinate mismatch, I would suggest that the target we use for comparison is something that doesn't depend on them, and that that something could be the Lebesgue integral (i.e. 'vertical bar area') of the curves clipped to the reference material's range.

If we pretend the slopes are perfectly linear as far as we care, that area is the sum of all the small triangles formed by the slopes times their span, 
plus the area of each remaining rectangle. In practice, this would be:

$$
\sum_1^N
(0.5 * \frac{X_N-X_{N-1}}{Y_N-Y_{N-1}}*(Y_N-Y_{N-1}))
+ 
((X_N-X_{N-1})*(max(Y_{ref})-(Y_N-Y_{N-1})))
$$

If the material we propose has a starting point above that of the client's, we'll also need to backfill the first rectangle for its area by adding a single $min(X_opt)*max(Y_{ref})-(Y_0-min(Y_ref))$.

Note that since we flipped the graph, the higher, the *weaker* the material, i.e. the more it yields to force.

Now, we have just two scalars, so it's just a matter of defining how exactly you want the loss to behave. There's a couple of options, e.g.

$$L(opt) = |A_{opt}-A_{ref}| + max(0, (A_{opt}-A_{ref}))$$
or
$$L(opt) = |A_{opt}-A_{ref}|
\ if\ (A_{opt}-A_{ref}) < 0
\\ else\ (A_{opt}-A_{ref})^2$$

The material that is the closest in the displacement response is the one with minimum loss. Note that I got lazy in that integration, since in theory you could have some negative nonlinearities in the displacement function, which would mean you have to calculate trapezoids.